# Makefile findstring won't match numerical character

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
CLANG_MAJOR_VER = x`${CXX} --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $$3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $$1 }'`xx

PAT = x6
CLANG_NAME = `${CXX} --version | grep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $$1}'`
CLANG_DEF = $(if $(findstring $(PAT),$(CLANG_MAJOR_VER)),abc,def)

all:
    @echo $(CLANG_MAJOR_VER)
    @echo $(CLANG_NAME)
    @echo $(CLANG_DEF)
```

Result :

```
x6xx
clang
```

and if PAT is x or xx, then $(CLANG_DEF) will be abc, if PAT = 6, x6, 6x then $(CLANG_DEF) is def.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. With your code (but hard-coding `CLANG_MAJOR_VER = x6xx`) I get `abc`. I am using GNU Make 3.81, what version are you using?

Comment: As the answer suggested, the problem is backticks expansion time. If you hard coded the value, then there is no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of backticks would be fine in a shell script but it is not in a Makefile. The recursive assignments (`VAR = VALUE`) assign the exact right-hand-side strings to your variables and make expands them recursively when they are needed and only then, that is, in your case, when make expands the recipe of your `all` rule, just before passing it to the shell. So, if `PAT = x6`, when `CLANG_DEF` is expanded you have (decomposed in successive steps):

1. `@echo $(CLANG_DEF)`
2. `@echo $(if $(findstring $(PAT),$(CLANG_MAJOR_VER)),abc,def)`
3. `` @echo $(if $(findstring x6,x`${CXX} --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $$3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $$1 }'`xx),abc,def) ``
4. `` @echo $(if $(findstring x6,x`clang --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $1 }'`xx),abc,def) ``
5. `@echo $(if ,abc,def)`
6. `@echo def`

And this does not depend on the result of the evaluation by the shell of:

```
clang --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $1 }'
```

because it is **not** evaluated by the shell, it is only considered as a string by make when expanding `$(findstring...)`...

But if `PAT = x`, the recursive expansion becomes:

1. `@echo $(CLANG_DEF)`
2. `@echo $(if $(findstring $(PAT),$(CLANG_MAJOR_VER)),abc,def)`
3. `` @echo $(if $(findstring x,x`${CXX} --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $$3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $$1 }'`xx),abc,def) ``
4. `` @echo $(if $(findstring x,x`clang --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $1 }'`xx),abc,def) ``
5. `@echo $(if x,abc,def)`
6. `@echo abc`

Instead of this unusual use of backsticks you could try to use the `$(shell...)` make function:

```
CLANG_MAJOR_VER = x$(shell ${CXX} --version | egrep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $$3}' | awk '{ gsub(/\./, " "); print $$1 }')xx

PAT = x6
CLANG_NAME = $(shell ${CXX} --version | grep -i 'clang' | awk '{print $$1}')
CLANG_DEF = $(if $(findstring $(PAT),$(CLANG_MAJOR_VER)),abc,def)

all:
    @echo $(CLANG_MAJOR_VER)
    @echo $(CLANG_NAME)
    @echo $(CLANG_DEF)
```

And, by the way, your way of retrieving the version major number is not very robust (indeed, it fails on my Mac OS). Something like:

```
clang --version | sed -n '/version/s/.*version \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

may be a bit better (not %100 sure, tested only on two OSes and two clang versions).

Comment: Thanks for your response and the sed script. The script I use is just a simplified version of real case. I use the awk script because the compiler choices are more than just clang++, g++ are the other one that need to support. clang++ --version will have something like 'clang version x.x.x ...', g++ --version will have output like 'gcc (GCC) x.x.x'

Answer (score 0):

There is [a library](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which can dissect simple (glob) string expressions:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

define clang--version = 
clang version 3.18.240-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
endef

parsed-string = $(call glob-match,$(clang--version),clang version *.*.*-* *Target: *Thread model: *InstalledDir: *)
$(info $(parsed-string))
$(info Major: $(word 2,$(parsed-string)) Minor: $(word 4,$(parsed-string)) Bugfix: $(word 6,$(parsed-string)))
```

Output:

```
clang§version§ 3 . 18 . 240 - 2ubuntu4 § (tags/RELEASE_380/final) Target:§ x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread§model:§ posix InstalledDir:§ /usr/bin
Major: 3 Minor: 18 Bugfix: 240
```